# Is there an advantage to block level based vs file based software updates

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, software-update

I see that there are these two ways to do software updates. Regular linux does file based updates but Android shifted to block based updates. Is there an advantage to this?

How does a block level update do differential updates which are by definition at a file level?

Answer (score 1):

Block level updates are easier to control, and (from a vendors point of view) more secure - although a fair amount of that security comes from limiting the device owners control of their system. Some of this comes from signing the image and limiting who can sign images and preventing unsigned images from running.

On the flip side, it greatly limits the scope of the software - there will be close tie-ins between the image and the exact hardware.

In some ways GNU Linux actually is quite similar to block level updates typically relying on an "initrd" which is a compressed filesystem which then a day off to the distro - the difference being that this block is recreated/repackaged as required, and it's designed to be lightweight and pass off control early in the process. Of-course, securing the boot process on GNU Linux is very difficult - and distris don't seem to do it (while it's the norm on Android)

Comment: Block level updates require that the rootfs be read-only right? If that changes then the file locations are no longer guaranteed and  differential updates cannot be done and hopefully the hash check also will fail on it.